# Is there an analytic solution to this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When trying to model a physical process I've ended up with the following equation (where a, b and c are just constants):

$\ddot{x} = a \cdot \dot{x}^2 + b \cdot sin(x) - c \cdot cos(x)$

I'll admit my calculus skills have degraded quite a bit after years out of college and heavy reliance of numerical solvers to do most things for me, so it might just be me being clueless but I don't even know where to start with this one.

Comment: Honestly I don't think that diffeq has an analytical solution. You might be better off using numerical methods.

Comment: Putting your diffeq into mathematica returns ``````{{y[x] -> 
   InverseFunction[
     Inactive[Integrate][-(Sqrt[1 + 4 a^2]/Sqrt[
        E^(2 a K[1]) C[1] + 4 a^2 E^(2 a K[1]) C[1] - 2 b Cos[K[1]] + 
         4 a c Cos[K[1]] - 4 a b Sin[K[1]] - 2 c Sin[K[1]]]), {K[1], 
        1, #1}] &][x + C[2]]}, {y[x] -> 
   InverseFunction[
     Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[1 + 4 a^2]/Sqrt[
       E^(2 a K[2]) C[1] + 4 a^2 E^(2 a K[2]) C[1] - 2 b Cos[K[2]] + 
        4 a c Cos[K[2]] - 4 a b Sin[K[2]] - 2 c Sin[K[2]]], {K[2], 
        1, #1}] &][x + C[2]]}}`````` so I doubt there's a good solution

Comment: Ok, thanks. I kind of expected it but It's good to have a little sanity check

Comment: If that is supposed to describe some physical situation, a pendulum where the rest position is not down, then the friction term should be $a|\dot x|\dot x$ to always give energy dissipation.